# jquery selector for div with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this below. I think the return Object of **$("div.tab_select")[0]** isn't a jQuery Object, but I can't even use pure javascript method.

Is there any way to make it jQuery Object? for instance **$($("div.tab_select")[0])**..I know this's silly;

Thank you for reading.

```
var tmp = $("div.tab_select")[0]; 
alert(tmp); //This gives me HTMLDivElement collectly. But I can't use any of javascript..

alert(tmp.nodeName); //But this give me error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined"

tmp.hide(); //Neither, I can't use this.
```

Comment: Try `var tmp = $("div.tab_select:first");` or `var tmp = $("div.tab_select:eq(0)");`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
// all divs with tab_select class
$('div.tab_select')

// first div with tab_select class
$('div.tab_select:first')

// or CSS pseudo selector which is slightly faster than the first jQuery 
// shortcut 
$('div.tab_select:first-of-type')

// or
$('div.tab_select').first()

// or
$('div.tab_select:eq(0)')

// or
$('div.tab_select').eq(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want a jQuery object use `var tmp = $("div.tab_select:first")` instead.

`var tmp = $("div.tab_select")[0]` will return the DOM element (if exists)

Answer (score 1):

Just do `$(tmp)`. [0] gives you the HTML-Element not the JQuery instance.

Answer (score 0):

I read it somewhere that css selectors are faster.

```
$('div.tab_select:nth-child(n)').<method>
```

here is the [e.g.](http://jsfiddle.net/z7CEU/)